# Laravel - Undefined variable if query returns no results

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

If a query does not have any results, which is possible, the variable the query is assigned to returns the error 'undefined variable $alerts' on the line `if(!$alerts)`.

```
foreach($locations as $location)
    {
        $alerts = Alert::where('location_id', '=', $location)
        ->lists('id');
    }

if(!$alerts){
        return Redirect::to('/users/')->with('message-warning', 
                                      'No matches have been found yet.');
    }
```

The `$alerts` variable is not anywhere else within the controller.

Even if the query returns no results, it should still be able to check it through `if(!$alerts)`?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your code looks wrong to me, at first why using a db query inside a loop and after the last loop the `$alerts` will be one last item.

Comment: Are you trying to build an array of `$alerts` inside your loop? If so, you should use `$alerts[] = Alert::where...`, otherwise you'll just return the alert from the last location in the loop.

Comment: @TheAlpha, @Damiani, you're both correct - I completely overlooked this. `$alerts[]` returns all results. Many thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
$alerts = Alert::whereIn('location_id', $locations)->lists('id');

if(!$alerts) {

    return Redirect::to('/users/')->with('message-warning', 'Your message!');
}
```

It's better, only one query will be executed.

Comment: the 'WhereIn' statement would remove the need for the `forloop` surrounding it? I have other `where` statements which I removed to simplify the formula, I can add this after I assume?

Comment: If you use `whereIn` then it'll look for all the items in the array using one DB query.

Comment: And I can remove the `foreach($locations as $location)` surrounding it?

Comment: Yes, exactly, why don't you just try it :-)

Comment: Thank you @TheAlpha for the explanation. You should update the Laravel docs with yours!

Comment: Don't use any DB query inside any loop, each query to the DB server is very expensive.

Comment: Unfortunately when using `WhereHas`, I am presented with this error - `Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::whereHas() must be an instance of Closure, string given`

Comment: I've used `whereIn` not `whereHas`!

Comment: Also, make sure your `$locations` not `$location` variable is an `Array`.

Comment: that explains my second issue. I have changed it to `whereIn` and `$locations` now I am getting `Array to string conversion error.` I initialise my  `$location` variable  like so `$locations = null;` Would that matter?

Comment: This is the static syntax `->whereIn('location_id', [1, 2, 3])->lists();` so make sure that your `$locations` contains data and yes, `$locations = null` will cause that error.

Comment: Right, I see. The problem is, I check if `$locations` exist, if not I redirect the user - `if(!$locations){redirect user..}`. And if I take the initialising of `null` out, it returns an error which is why this thread started! Thank you for your help though @TheAlpha, I appreciate it.

Comment: Then you should check `if(!empty($locations)) { //redirect }`.

Answer (score 0):

When `$locations` is empty, the foreach won't loop, and `$alerts` won't be initialized. I suggest initializing the variable before the loop:

```
$alerts = null;

foreach ($locations as $location) { }

if(!$alerts) { }
```

Comment: Works perfectly, many thanks @DamienPirsy. I can accept an answer in 9 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't execute query into a loop, even if you do that make sure you store the results in a array instead of a variable because then your result will always be the last row of the query. You should declare $alert variable/array before going into the foreach loop, so that if your query doesn't returns any result your variable/array will still be there, in your case if your query doesn't return any result you don't have $alert variable at all.